# Databinding not showing values

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, data-binding

I have a tab control that is loading tab pages and content on load. All of my logic is working and generating the look and style correctly, however none of my data is being data bound.

TabControl.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                    SelectedIndex="0"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource templateForTheContent}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateForTheHeader}">
        </TabControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

<DataTemplate x:Key="templateForTheContent" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
</DataTemplate>

<local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
                              TextBoxDataTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxDataTemplate}"
                              ComboBoxDataTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxDataTemplate}" 
                              MultiValueDataTemplate="{StaticResource MultiValueDataTemplate}"/>

<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=TwoWay}" ></Label>
    <ComboBox  Margin="8,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ComboBox1" SelectedIndex="0">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DropDownOpened}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

My control is bound to the TabViewModel

```
Public Property Tabs As ObservableCollection(Of dmsTab)
```

And my dmsTab

```
Public Property Fields As ObservableCollection(Of FieldViewModel)
```

FieldViewModel.vb

```
Public Property Field As Field
```

And my Field has the Caption and value Properties that I'm trying to Databind to. Is this how I should be doing this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Your properties aren't public?

Comment: @Will I don't think that matters, but I went ahead and tried it anyway and updated the question. Still no luck.

Comment: Data binding absolutely, positively only works with public properties. If you missed that fact, I'm betting you missed other simple stuff. I'd grab Snoop and examine your bindings at runtime. It's easier than turning on expressive binding messages in the debugger and crawling through the nonsense that results in the debug window.

Comment: @Will -- not true at all. You can bind to "internal" properties via XAML as you normally would. It is entirely possible to bind to private properties via code and there are legit reasons to do so. Personally, I find binding from code to be a pain, so I just use the internal trick.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Thanks for splitting that hair. I hope you didn't just confuse the crap out of the OP.

Comment: Can you try to clarify what bindings do work, and which ones don't? For example, is the Tabs binding working OK? If not, you'll want to double-check your DataContext for the whole control. Or is it the Caption binding? Or perhaps the ComboBox binding to the Value property? I agree with Will that your best bet will be to start up something like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and see if you can figure what is wrong with your DataContext hierarchy. I can't really tell from the code you've posted, but I suspect you may have an extra level (the property `Field`) in your code

Comment: @Rachel all of my bindings work except the Caption and Value bindings on the Field itself. Is there a limit to how far down DataBindings will go?

Comment: @bme2010 No, however I suspect your DataContext is setup so you have `Tabs[X].Fields[N].Field.Caption`, while your XAML is looking for `Tabs[X].Fields[N].Caption`. Try changing your binding to something like `<Label Content="{Binding Path=Field.Caption}" />` to include that extra level in the hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an extra level in your DataContext's hierarchy

Based on the code you've posted, your XAML bindings are trying to find the property at

```
Tabs[X].Fields[N].Caption
```

However your code structure is

```
Tabs[X].Fields[N].Field.Caption
```

Try changing your bindings to include the `Field` property, like this :

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Field.Caption}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Field.Value}" SelectedIndex="0">
        ...
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Alternatively, you could set the `DataContext` of the entire StackPanel if your templates are complex and have a lot of bindings

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Field}">
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Caption}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" SelectedIndex="0">
        ...
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `{Binding}` syntax from a DataTemplate doesn't work like that because it doesn't have the right DataContext. I do something like:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xxx}}, Path=blah}
```

in my DataTemplates and it works.